# Question from Real Analysis -- making proof cleaner

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm taking my first real analysis class after about maybe 7 years from the last time I took one. I have a question about how to make my proof nicer. The question is: Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a mapping. Let $Y_\alpha,{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of subsets of Y. I need to prove $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} f^{-1}(Y_\alpha)$

So here's how I tried it.

Fix $a \in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha) = \left\lbrace x \in X : f(x) \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha \right\rbrace$. Then $f(a) \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}Y_\alpha$, so there exists some $\beta \in A$ so that $f(a) \in Y_\beta$. This implies that $a \in f^{-1}(Y_\beta)$, and hence $a \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} f^{-1}(Y_\alpha)$

This shows containment one way. I haven't written it out but I assume to show the other containment is similar. It seems however, that there should be a bit more elegant way to write this than how I did. I think the work I did was right, but is there a way to make it cleaner?

Comment: In what way do you consider your proof not "clean"?  It looks like exactly the proof I would write.

Comment: @EricWofsey I suppose it seemed like there might've been some steps that were redundant and could've been cut out.

Answer (score -1):

You can write in this way

$a \in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha) = \left\lbrace x \in X : f(x) \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} Y_\alpha \right\rbrace$ $\iff$ $f(a) \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}Y_\alpha$ $\iff$ $ \exists \beta$ s.t $ f(a) \in Y_\beta$   $\iff$ $\exists \beta$ s.t $a \in f^{-1}(Y_{\beta})$$\iff$ $a \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} f^{-1}(Y_\alpha)$

Comment: Writing the existential quantifier in semiformal notation underneath one of the bi-implications in the chain is extremely confusing (you certainly should *not* be existentially quantifying the bi-implication).

Comment: Actually writting in this " $\iff$" notation you can not put it any other suitable place. I agree it is little bit confusive but making a student understand this is not harmful I think.

Comment: Why not put the existential quantifiers where they belong: $\ldots \Leftrightarrow (\exists\beta\cdot f(a) \in Y_{\beta})\Leftrightarrow (\exists \beta \cdot a \in f^{-1}(Y_{\beta})) \Leftrightarrow \ldots $? Being slapdash about the scope of quantifiers is usually very harmful.

Comment: Yeah nice idea. In this way it can be written.